# Installation error in Service mesh Linkerd service mesh in aks

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, linkerd

I have followed the getting started instructions here: **https://linkerd.io/2/getting-started/** for installing linkerd but i am not able to install cli of linkerd.

Please see the command below: **curl -sL https://run.linkerd.io/install | sh**

Please see the error below:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option
```

Can anyone please help me to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried with -k? `curl -ksL https://run.linkerd.io/install | sh`

Comment: Yes i have with -k and --insecure but i am getting same result. Can you please try in your cmd.

Comment: I have tried and it works even without `-k`. Are you behind a proxy or something? Please try using a slightly different command: `wget https://run.linkerd.io/install; sh install`

Comment: You mean curl wget https://run.linkerd.io/install; sh install

Comment: No, only `wget https://run.linkerd.io/install; sh install`. Are you running this on Windows? These commands are meant for Linux or Mac.

Comment: You can get the package for windows [here](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/releases/download/edge-20.5.2/linkerd2-cli-edge-20.5.2-windows.exe).

Comment: To use this package, download it, rename to linkerd.exe and use it according to the instructions.

Comment: Yes my bad i was checking in powershell where it is not working but it is working in cmd. Thankyou so much.

Comment: One thing i have observed is that the linkerd cli only works only in the directory of the download exe file from cmd. I was missing this before.

Comment: I am facing new error when i run **linkerd check --pre** the error is **Error rendering install manifest: open /add-ons\grafana/Chart.yaml: file does not exist .** @mWatney can you please help me.

Comment: Regarding the curl Issue. Can you share your os version and flavour et version of curl.

Comment: Thanks for replying the details are as follows os version: **1803 osbuild 17134.1488** and i am using windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation error while installing Service mesh Linkerd service mesh in aks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796172/installation-error-while-installing-service-mesh-linkerd-service-mesh-in-aks)

Answer (score 0):

The provides installation instructions from the Linkerd website are indeed vague, they provide instruction for Linux (shell) users as well as a `brew install` command for OSX users.

If you are interested in installing LinkerD on your Windows machine, the recommandation is to download the binary (.exe - for Windows) directly form their release page: https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/releases

After you have downloaded the binary, you should be able to update your %PATH% environment variable to add the location of the binary, this will allow you to refer to the `linkerd` directly from your command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Linkerd started supporting Windows with a Chocolatey package: https://chocolatey.org/packages/Linkerd2

To use it, make sure that you have Chocolatey installed and run:

```
choco install linkerd2
```

After the installation, verify that the install was successful with:

```
linkerd --help
```

You should see the list of commands available to the Linkerd CLI.

Comment: Please add more details in answer, and try to do it without links to other sites

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ivan. I hope this answer is helpful.