# Installation error while installing Service mesh Linkerd service mesh in aks

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, linkerd

I have followed the getting started instructions here: https://linkerd.io/2/getting-started/ for installing linkerd but i am facing error at step 3. The details are as follows.

Please see the command: **linkerd install | kubectl apply -f -**

Please see the error below:

```
Error: open /add-ons\grafana/Chart.yaml: file does not exist
Usage:
  linkerd install [flags]
  linkerd install [command]

Examples:
  # Default install.
  linkerd install | kubectl apply -f -

  # Install Linkerd into a non-default namespace.
  linkerd install -l linkerdtest | kubectl apply -f -

  # Installation may also be broken up into two stages by user privilege, via
  # subcommands.

Available Commands:
  config        Output Kubernetes cluster-wide resources to install Linkerd
  control-plane Output Kubernetes control plane resources to install Linkerd
```

Can anyone please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better work with Microsoft documentation  - [Install Linkerd in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/servicemesh-linkerd-install?pivots=client-operating-system-linux).

The following steps worked for me :

```sh
# Get AKS credentials
az aks get-credentials --resource-group $(resource_group_name) --name $(cluster_name)

# Download stable release
curl -sLO "https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/releases/download/stable-2.6.1/linkerd2-cli-stable-2.6.1-linux"

# Copy the linkerd client binary to the standard user program location in your PATH
sudo cp ./linkerd2-cli-stable-2.6.1-linux /usr/local/bin/linkerd  
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/linkerd

#Check linkerd pre if pass with no issue - install Linkerd on AKS
 if linkerd check --pre; then
        linkerd install | kubectl apply -f -
    fi
```

Comment: Thanks for replying can you please let me know how did you run sudo commands on windows machine?

Comment: install wsl : https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: Thankyou so much for this document i was searching for it, I got an configuration error at  az login that says **SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)**, However that is being temperately solved by setting env variable **AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION=1**. I am accepting this answer as i am able to install linkerd thankyou so much.

Comment: Glad i could help :)